# React - I can't see my response from fetch post

Tags: reactjs, fetch

Im don't think this needs a bind to see the response but I must be missing something because im getting a response back from this Fetch/post.  Here is my fetch.

```
 export default class Test extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = { value: '' };

this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}
componentDidMount() { }

 handleChange(event) {
this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
}

 handleSubmit(event, cb) {
   event.preventDefault();

return (
  fetch('test/post', 'POST')
    .then(response => {
      if (response.status >= 400) {
        this.setState({
          value: 'error',
        });
        throw new Error('Throw Error');
      }
      console.log('REACT::RESPONSE', response.json());
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(cb)
    .catch(() => {
      this.setState({
        value: 'error cb',
      });
    })
);
  }
```

the post looks good. It hits my webApi, and I get a response back.  Im using fiddler to view the http traffic on my dev workstation.  Here is what the response message looks like in fiddler from my webApi.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 08 Feb 2017 22:49:27 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 16

{"name":"MyName"}
```

Currently MYRESPONSE:: console log just shows.

```
MYRESPONSE::[object Promise]
```

or "MYRESPONSE::"+JSON.stringify(response) shows

```
MYRESPONSE::{}
```

Comment: How do you use the `handleSubmit` function?

Comment: @Khang it's a basic form submit.  <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.json()` returns a promise. You need to do `.json().then(data => console.log(data))`

Comment: yeap, that was it.  Thanks greatly.  Accepted and upvoted.